# Kibana Server Not Ready 7.10

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-7

I followed this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gZb7HpVOges&lc=UgytpC8Evhfmld7YeBV4AaABAg.9GmQvwXZKJC9GmSBBrUcxY

to the T on my virtual box instance of Ubuntu 20.

Elastic appears to run fine however when I try to run kibana I receive "Kibana Server Not Ready" Error.
Both elastic and kibana are 7.10

When I run a journalctl -u kibana.serviceI receive:

```
Dec 03 14:04:25 elk kibana[647]: {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-12-03T14:04:25Z","tags":["error","elasticsearch","data"],"pid":647,"message":"[ConnectionError]: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9200"}
Dec 03 14:04:27 elk kibana[647]: {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-12-03T14:04:27Z","tags":["error","elasticsearch","data"],"pid":647,"message":"[ConnectionError]: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9200"}
Dec 03 14:04:30 elk kibana[647]: {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-12-03T14:04:30Z","tags":["error","elasticsearch","data"],"pid":647,"message":"[ConnectionError]: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9200"}
Dec 03 14:04:32 elk kibana[647]: {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-12-03T14:04:32Z","tags":["error","elasticsearch","data"],"pid":647,"message":"[ConnectionError]: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9200"}
Dec 03 14:04:35 elk kibana[647]: {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-12-03T14:04:35Z","tags":["error","elasticsearch","data"],"pid":647,"message":"[ConnectionError]: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9200"}
Dec 03 14:04:37 elk kibana[647]: {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-12-03T14:04:37Z","tags":["error","elasticsearch","data"],"pid":647,"message":"[ConnectionError]: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9200"}
Dec 03 14:04:40 elk kibana[647]: {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-12-03T14:04:40Z","tags":["error","elasticsearch","data"],"pid":647,"message":"[ConnectionError]: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9200"}
Dec 03 14:04:42 elk kibana[647]: {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-12-03T14:04:42Z","tags":["error","elasticsearch","data"],"pid":647,"message":"[ConnectionError]: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9200"}
Dec 03 14:04:45 elk kibana[647]: {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-12-03T14:04:45Z","tags":["error","elasticsearch","data"],"pid":647,"message":"[ConnectionError]: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9200"}
Dec 03 14:04:47 elk kibana[647]: {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-12-03T14:04:47Z","tags":["error","elasticsearch","data"],"pid":647,"message":"[ConnectionError]: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9200"}
Dec 03 14:04:50 elk kibana[647]: {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-12-03T14:04:50Z","tags":["error","elasticsearch","data"],"pid":647,"message":"[ConnectionError]: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9200"}
Dec 03 14:04:52 elk kibana[647]: {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-12-03T14:04:52Z","tags":["error","elasticsearch","data"],"pid":647,"message":"[ConnectionError]: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9200"}
```

**Elastic Yml**

```
cluster.name: lab

node.name: lab1

path.data: /var/lib/elasticsearch
path.logs: /var/log/elasticsearch

bootstrap.memory_lock: true

network.host: 0.0.0.0
http.port: 9200

discovery.type: 'single-node'

indices.query.bool.max_clause_count: 8192
search.max_buckets: 250000

action.destructive_requires_name: 'true'

reindex.remote.whitelist: '*:*'

xpack.monitoring.enabled: 'true'
xpack.monitoring.collection.enabled: 'true'
xpack.monitoring.collection.interval: 30s

xpack.security.enabled: 'true'
xpack.security.audit.enabled: 'false'

node.ml: 'false'
xpack.ml.enabled: 'false'

xpack.watcher.enabled: 'false'

xpack.ilm.enabled: 'true'

xpack.sql.enabled: 'true'
```

**Kibana Yml**

```
server.name: 'lab1'
server.host: '0.0.0.0'
server.port: 5601

server.maxPayloadBytes: 8388608

elasticsearch.hosts: ['http://127.0.0.1:9200']
elasticsearch.username: 'kibana'
elasticsearch.password: 'changeme'

elasticsearch.requestTimeout: 132000
elasticsearch.shardTimeout: 120000

kibana.index: '.kibana'

#kibana.defaultAppId: 'dashboard/<dashboard_id>'

#logging.quiet: true
#logging.timezone: 'UTC'

vega.enableExternalUrls: true

console.enabled: true

xpack.security.enabled: true
xpack.security.audit.enabled: false

xpack.monitoring.enabled: true
xpack.monitoring.kibana.collection.enabled: true
xpack.monitoring.kibana.collection.interval: 30000

xpack.monitoring.ui.enabled: true
xpack.monitoring.min_interval_seconds: 30
#xpack.monitoring.ui.container.elasticsearch.enabled: 'false'

#xpack.apm.enabled: true
#xpack.apm.ui.enabled: true

xpack.grokdebugger.enabled: true
```

Comment: Please share elasticsearch.yml and kibana.yml

Comment: I added them to the post thanks

Comment: What do you get on accessing `http://127.0.0.1:9200` via web or curl?

Comment: i get : 
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"security_exception","reason":"missing authentication credentials for REST request [/]"                                                                                         ,"header":{"WWW-Authenticate":"Basic realm=\"security\" charset=\"UTF-8\""}}],"type":"security_exception","reason":"mis                                                                                         sing authentication credentials for REST request [/]","header":{"WWW-Authenticate":"Basic realm=\"security\" charset=\"

Comment: When I use the browser and I put in the IP:9200 I get a login which I set up via that video. I then get  
name "lab1"
cluster_name "lab"
cluster_uuid "tcOqagttQjKGe_BTH-JPWA"
version 
number "7.10.0"
build_flavor "default"
build_type "deb"
build_hash "51e9d6f22758d0374a0f3f5c6e8f3a7997850f96"
build_date "2020-11-09T21:30:33.964949Z"
build_snapshot false
lucene_version "8.7.0"
minimum_wire_compatibility_version "6.8.0"
minimum_index_compatibility_version "6.0.0-beta1"
tagline "You Know, for Search"

Comment: The simple way is to deploy using Docker containers. https://jinnabalu.tech/Elasticsearch-Kibana-using-Docker-Compose/

Comment: docker is a little out of my realm. Im looking to do it on VM box first.